# How to use js libraries with typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need 'react-keydown' module in my project but i cant find typing's for it .
How can I use this module in my typescript project?

Comment: I got answer that I should  use "--allowJs" flag. But  i don't understand how to correctly include library if i compile with this flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript need to recognize your JS library as a Typescript. To achieve this you need a ".d.ts" file (react-keydown.d.ts), It's a interface for the JS functions.
There's a Github called DefinitelyTyped and they have React there.
I don't know if you only want one function or if this can help but here's the link.

[DefinitelyTyped/react](Https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/react)

[npm Reference](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react)

Comment: That link throws 404

Comment: It seems they changed the repository structure. I already updated the link and added a reference to npm.

Answer (score 1):

Joao mentioned DefinitelyTyped which is where you should start. If you can't find the library there you either need to create your own definition or declare the 3rd party library as `any`. You won't get any typedefs of course but you will be able to compile and use the library.

```
declare var ThirdPartyLibrary;
ThirdPartyLibrary.doStuff();
```